# 400 error on publishing go dependencies in Jfrog artifactory

Tags: go, artifactory, jfrog-cli, goproxy

We are trying to publish some go dependencies in jfrog artifactory using the below command:

jf go-publish v1.2.3 --self=false --deps=ALL

with jfrog cli account config:

```
Server ID:                      demo-go-repo-local
JFrog platform URL:             https://artifactory.test.com:8081/
Artifactory URL:                https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/
Distribution URL:               https://artifactory.test.com:8081/distribution/
Xray URL:                       https://artifactory.test.com:8081/xray/
Mission Control URL:            https://artifactory.test.com:8081/mc/
Pipelines URL:                  https://artifactory.test.com:8081/pipelines/
User:                           admin
Password:                       ***
Default:                        true
```

but getting following bad request error with 400 error:

```
[ Warn] (Attempt 3) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/api/go/go-modules/github.com/grpc/@v/v1.2.3.zip;go.version=v1.2.3: Put "https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/api/go/go-modules/github.com/grpc/@v/v1.2.3.zip;go.version=v1.2.3": local error: tls: bad record MAC
[ Warn] (Attempt 4) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/api/go/go-modules/github.com/grpc/@v/v1.2.3.zip;go.version=v1.2.3: server response: 400
[Info] executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
{
  "status": "failure",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
[Error] server response: 400
```

Can anyone please suggest if we are missing something in publish request.

Comment: The error `local error: tls: bad record MAC` hints at a TLS problem. What happens with `openssl s_client -connect artifactory.test.com:443` ?